# Formatting the results from solving a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting

```
{{x[t] -> 600 (t + I π t - 50 Log[50] + t Log[50] + 50 Log[50 - t] - t Log[-50 + t])}}
```

After solving a differential equation, I get an answer in a form where I want to get rid of irrational values. How can it be implemented? Function `N` doesn't help.

```
x0 = 15000; y0 = 10; m0 = 150; v0 = 210; G = 3; u = 600; g = 9.8;
v1[h_] := Sqrt[v0^2 - 2 g h];
t1[h_] := (v0 - v1[h])/g;
M[t_] := m0 - G t;
DSolve[{M[t] x ''[t] == G u, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t] // FullSimplify
DSolve[{M[t] y ''[t] == -M[t] g, y[0] == h, y'[0] == v1[h]}, y[t], t] // FullSimplify
```

This is the full code fragment. I need to obtain a plot.

Comment: What was the equation? What irrational values do you mean? As posted your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: In my equation was i*Pi*t, moderator edited my post addition of the tag code. I need to get rid of i (root of minus one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: added detail for provided equations.

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
x0 = 15000; y0 = 10; m0 = 150; v0 = 210; G = 3; u = 600; g = 98/10;
v1[h_] = Sqrt[v0^2 - 2 g h];
t1[h_] = (v0 - v1[h])/g;
M[t_] = m0 - G t;

Clear[x, y]

x[t_] = x[t] /. DSolve[
     {M[t] x''[t] == G u, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0},
     x[t], t][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

This satisfies the equations in the `DSolve`:

```
{M[t] x''[t] == G u, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0} // Simplify
```

> {True, True, True}

To identify the conditions for `x[t]` to be real,

```
Reduce[{Element[x[t], Reals], Element[t, Reals]}, t] // Quiet
```

> t < 50

```
x[t_] = x[t] // FullSimplify[#, t < 50] &
```

[image]

Confirming the condition for `x[t]` real: for the `Log` to produce a real value, its argument must be positive, i.e.,

```
Reduce[-50/(t - 50) > 0, t]
```

> t < 50

```
y[t_, h_] = y[t] /. DSolve[
     {M[t] y''[t] == -M[t] g, y[0] == h, y'[0] == v1[h]},
     y[t], t][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

In the equations in the `DSolve` the dependence on `h` is implicit. To substitute `y[t, h]` into the equations, define

```
y[t_] = y[t, h];
```

This satisfies the equations in the `DSolve`:

```
{M[t] y''[t] == -M[t] g, y[0] == h, y'[0] == v1[h]} // Simplify
```

> {True, True, True}

To keep `y[t, h]` real, the argument of the `Sqrt` must be nonnegative.

```
Reduce[900 - 2 h/5 >= 0, h]
```

> h <= 2250

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[{x[t], y[t, h]}, {t, 0, 300/7},
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "x(t),\ny(t, h)"},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 300/7}, {0, 5000}},
    PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "y(t, h)"},
    ImageSize -> 324],
   NSolve[{y[t, h] == 0, 0 < t <= 300/7}, t][[1]]}],
 {{h, 0}, 0, 2250, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t, h]}, {t, 0, 300/7},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 17500}, {0, 2275}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "y(t, h)"}],
 {{h, 0}, 0, 2250, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: What does mean [[1]] in first DSolve x[t] ?

Comment: Evaluate the `DSolve` with and without the `[[1]]` and compare the results. Alternatively, select either the two left brackets or the two right brackets and press `F1` for help. As for the `Reduce`, I used Mathematica version 10.1 on a Mac, perhaps you used a different version or a different operating system.

Comment: I don't understand( Can u say me, on understandable language, what is it? Plz

Comment: Read the documentation for `Part`

Comment: And this part M[t] x''[t] == G u?

Comment: It is your equation in your question. Why are you asking me to explain it?

Comment: Thank you, figured. Sorry for my inattention

Answer (score 0):

```
DSolve[{M[t] x ''[t] == G u, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t] // 
 FullSimplify[#, t < 50] &
(* {{x[t] -> 600 (t + (-50 + t) Log[-(50/(-50 + t))])}} *)
```

cancels the explicit imaginary term for `t < 50`.  The imaginary term cannot be eliminated for larger `t` except by applying the boundary conditions in the first ODE at some `t` value greater than `50` rather than at `t == 0`.

Comment: You don't so much need to change the boundary conditions as the parameters.  The original equations have a singular point when $t = m_0/G$ ($t = 50$ for the provided code.)  I suppose there might be a solution that goes to a finite value in the neighborhood of $t = m_0/G$, in which case finely tuned boundary conditions at $t = 0$ would do the trick.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Perhaps, I should make clear that, so long as a singularity exists at `t==50`, the boundary conditions must be applied for `t > 50` in order to eliminate the imaginary term there.